# Accessibility Support - Hybrid Applications built with Cordova

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, accessibility, hybrid-mobile-app, screen-readers

Does anyone has built hybrid mobile application with accessibility(Talkback) support? Which framework has better support for accessibility? Has anyone tried frameworks like Ionic, Kendo UI or Onsen UI with accessibility as a feature?

I tried with Sencha touch and accessibility doesnt work well as in iOS devices you cannot scroll the list in accessibility mode and you cannot put Aria tags also as we dont have much access to DOM. Tried developing with plain HTML5 & javascript without any frameworks but its difficult to achieve the top class UI and maintain the code.

If anyone has accessibility related experience related to hybrid applications please give your thoughts. Thanks in advance.